# Java Renderer for column with FileChooser and Image at the same time

Tags: java, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I would like to know if it is possible to have a situation like this in Java:

I have a JTable that I want to implement a JFileChooser in a column, then, when the user select a file (which is an Image/Icon) from this FileChooser, then the Image/Icon is displyed in the same column (overriding the FileChooser object..).

As far as I know, one can implement his own Renderer but I don't know if you can make something like that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a cell editor as well as a renderer. Although people love to subtype unnecessarily when using Swing, you don't need to have the `JFileChooser` implement the renderer/editor. Then it's just a matter of swapping the component in play, or having the editor use `JFileChoose` and renderer use `JLabel`.

Comment: I guess the renderer is used to actually display what the user selected with the cell editor (which is the file chooser) and in this case it is an image, right?

Comment: @User1254 Probably. You might want to show some form of the `JFileChooser` in the renderer if nothing has yet been selected, though it'll still require the user to start editing the cell.